# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm working with `JS` [`ES6`], I'm able to display notification on the go, on clicking thi `x` icon, it's disappearing just fine, but if I let it to `timeout` it throws `Type Error`

```
Notify.js?49da:72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined
```

Here is my `class` snippet

```
class Notify {
    constructor() {
        this.html = '';
    }

    showNotification(text = 'Something went wrong!', style = 'warning'){
        //here I need to update this.html
        this.html = $(`<div class="alert  alert-${style}  hide">${this.icon}  ${text} </div>`);

        //close on click
        let vue = this;
        $('<a>', {
            text: '×',
            class: 'button close',
            style: 'padding-left: 10px;',
            href: '#',
            click: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                vue.removeNotice();
            }
        }).prependTo(vue.html);
        vue.container.prepend(vue.html);
        vue.html.removeClass('hide').hide().fadeIn('slow');
        var timer = setInterval(vue.removeNotice, vue.time);

        $(vue.html).hover(function () {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }, function () {
            timer = setInterval(vue.removeNotice, vue.time);
        });

        vue.html.on('click', function () {
            clearInterval(timer);
            vue.removeNotice()
        });

    }

    removeNotice() {
        console.dir(this.html);  //this just prints empty string
        this.html.stop().fadeOut('slow').remove()  //this line throws error.
    }
```

any clue where and what I'm doing wrong?
P.S I'm learning this stuff. and downvoter(s) please point to right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not binding this properly.

```
  timer = setInterval(vue.removeNotice.bind(this), vue.time);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a million. I wasn't actually thinking about this. JS is tricky :/